# Can i run functions after SELECT * FROM db WHERE in php?

Tags: php, url

I want to use a function after WHERE

like this it works

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Prodotti WHERE Id=10";
```

what if i want the id to be in the URL link?
the link example is this:   https://www.try.org/product.php?signup=98
this way it's not working

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Prodotti WHERE strpos($fullUrl, signup=Id)";
```

Comment: research `$_GET`

Comment: You can get signup via $_GET['signup']

Comment: `strpos` is not a mysql function, so that won't work.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy whilst this is valid, it's open to SQL injection

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy You probably should not recommend that as it's extremely vunerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Please don't directly pass the value. Use prepared statements and validate the input.

Comment: See this article: [PHP, The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) particularly the part about the _PDO_ extension and Parameterized SQL Queries...

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you want to do? Why do you want to use `strpos` for an ID?

Comment: i want the user to visit a link (he gets from a qr code) which is connected to the Id of a product. I won't use get i know sql injection, it can make possible to delete everything

Comment: Then why do you use `strpos` in your query? Why not use the ID from the URL?

Comment: because with strpos i can get the number from the url, and compare it with the Id in a query. what do you mean ID from the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `id` by using the [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) superglobal:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['signup']; // (int) makes sure it is an integer and no string
```

Now in order to make it work within your query you first need to make the input secure.
You can make an input secure by using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) but since you need an integer and not a string it is better to use a [`prepared statement`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

In your query you can than do

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Prodotti` WHERE `Id` = $id";
```

Use backticks around table and column names to prevent mysql reserved word error.

Example of prepared statement:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$id = (int) $_GET['signup']; 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Prodotti` WHERE `Id` = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);// i for integer s for string

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    // Do something with the fetched data

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: This is terrible advice for securing, the hint is in the function name `mysqli_real_escape_**string**`.

Comment: @Script47 that is whay is said it is better to use prepared statements

Comment: But why would you suggest incorrect code in the first place?

Comment: @Script47 it might be incorrect for this example but it is good to know for the OP in general to secure user inputs. It is also good to know the existence of different methods

Comment: Definitely good to know different methods but not when they are being used incorrectly, besides, escaping is pointless with prepared statements.

Comment: how can i use prepared statements?

Comment: '*it might be incorrect for this example*' - But you are answering *this* question so you should be giving correct information.

Comment: @Script47 better now?

Comment: @SuperDJ no, you are misunderstanding the purpose of that function, it doesn't make anything secure. It simply escapes a string.

Comment: @Script47 thus making a string secure for use in a query

Comment: @SuperDJ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391315/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-enough-to-avoid-sql-injection-or-other-sql-attack

Comment: well using (int) solves everything because only numbers will pass through

Comment: @Script47 I know it isn't a 100% "secure" but it is better to have some escaping/ "security" than not all. That being said nothing is a 100% secure

Comment: i just need little security that's enough for me

Comment: @LucaAgostinelli what about for your users? Are they happy with a "little"?

Comment: I'm a student and this project is not going online

Comment: @SuperDJ '*That being said nothing is a 100% secure*' - That seems like a case of whataboutism.

Comment: @LucaAgostinelli then learn the best while you are learning. Don't settle for average. If you aren't doing the best now what makes you think you will be doing the best when you have work deadlines?

Answer (score -3):

You can get the signup parameter from the url like this:

```
$signup = $_GET['signup'];
```

and then use it in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Prodotti WHERE Id = '$signup'";
```

but this is not secure, i suggest you also google for "php mysql prepared statements"

Comment: Why not just suggest the preferred way instead of showing bad code examples?

Comment: While this solution works, it is extremely vunerable to SQL injection. Consider revising this example to provide additional security...